# Querying Hadoop ORC Table from Azure SQL Data warehouse

Tags: azure, hadoop, orc, azure-synapse

I am having issues reading ORC table created in Azure HDInsight from Azure SQL Data warehouse. See below sequence I have followed to set up HDInsight instance as well as Azure SQL Data warehouse.

1. I created a text file(Sales.txt) with content as below

> 20150614|1|10.50
>   20150618|1|100.75
>  
>   20150924|1|89.75
>   20160214|2|10456.90
>  
>   20150922|3|34.70
>  
>   20151021|3|43.70
>  
>   20151225|3|65.90
>   20151231|3|87.50
>  
>   20160101|4|1349.40
>  
>   20160512|4|3982.40
>   20150608|5|398.90
>  
>   20150929|5|981.80
>  
>   20151225|5|482.80
>   20151231|5|289.60
>  
>   20160214|5|688.50
>  
>   20160531|5|682.80

2. I then created a HDInsight cluster in Azure
3. I created a database `hadoopdb`
4. I created an external table in that database using following query

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hadoopdb.salestxt
   (
       salesdate int,
       productid int,
       salesamt float
   )
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
   lines terminated by '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE 
   LOCATION 'wasbs:///<myclustercontainer>@<mystorageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/Sales.txt';
   ```
5. Loaded data using following query

   `LOAD DATA INPATH '/Sales.txt' INTO TABLE hadoopdb.salestxt;`
6. Then created an internal ORC table with following script

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hadoopdb.sales
   (
       salesdate int,
       productid int,
       salesamt float
   ) 
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' STORED AS ORC;
   ```
7. Moved data to ORC table with following query

   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hadoopdb.salesorc
      SELECT * FROM hadoopdb.salestxt
8. Executing following query, I do see results in Hive Editor

   `select * from hadoopdb.sales`
9. Back in Azure SQL data warehouse, created the DATA SOURCE using following query in SSMS,

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ORCAzureStorage WITH 
   (
       TYPE = HADOOP,
       LOCATION = 'wasbs://<myclustercontainer>@<mystorageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net',
       CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential
   ```

   );
10. Created an external file format using following

    ```
    CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT ORCdefault
    WITH 
    (   
        FORMAT_TYPE = ORC,
        DATA_COMPRESSION = 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec'
    );
    ```
11. Created schema `[hdp]`
12. Trying to create an EXTERNAL TABLE with script below

    ```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [hdp].FactSales 
    (
        salesdate int,
        productid int,
        salesamt float  
    )
    WITH 
    (
        LOCATION    ='/Sales.txt',
        DATA_SOURCE = ORCAzureStorage , 
        FILE_FORMAT = ORCdefault                
    );
    ```

However this query fails with following error

Msg 105002, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
EXTERNAL TABLE access failed because the specified path name '/Sales.txt/' does not exist. Enter a valid path and try again.

I have tried various combinations for LOCATION such as
'myclustercontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/Sales.txt/Sales.txt'

Sales.txt file exists in storage account at location
'myclustercontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/Sales.txt/Sales.txt'.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: You are missing a "/" at the end for your external table location make it `LOCATION    ='/Sales.txt/'`

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL DW does not currently support querying HDFS. You will need to move the data to a Windows Azure Storage Blob. 
There is a tutorial for this [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-blob-storage-with-polybase/)

Thanks!
Casey

Comment: Thanks Casey. I looked at the link you shared. However, it does not talk anything about ORC. The FILE FORMAT is TextFileFormat  rather than ORC. I have also changed Sandbox implementation to HDInsight. Question is now updated to reflect changes from HDFS to Azure Blob. Can you take a look?